# how to check and integrate enable cookies in WKWebview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

Am tried all the methods of enable cookies, its not working, safari browser working, wkwebview not working

Method 1:
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

```
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false
    config.preferences = preferences
    
    let cookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()
    config.websiteDataStore = cookieStore
    
    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    
    if let url = URL(string: "https://emerald-lyssa-85.tiiny.site/") {
        // Create a URLRequest with the URL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        // Load cookies from the request
        if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: url) {
            for cookie in cookies {
                webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            // Load the URLRequest in the webView
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

```
    guard let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          let url = navigationResponse.response.url else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    
    if let headerFields = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {
        let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url)
        cookies.forEach { cookie in
            webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

These methods are am tried its not working

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but..

In general, `WKWebView` has cookies enabled by default. You can access the store `WKWebView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore` and play with them using `getAllCookies(_:)` and `setCookie(_:)` methods, as you did.

By configuring `WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()` in your code snippet I assume, that you do not want to persist `WKWebView` cookies between consequent app launches. On the other hand, I conclude, you want to transfer the cookies saved previously in Safari to your `WKWebView` and that is why you try to read them from `HTTPCookieStorage.shared`.

In [HTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage) documentation we can read that:

> iOS — Each app and app extension has a unique data container, meaning
> they have separate cookie stores. You can obtain a common cookie
> storage by using the `sharedCookieStorage(forGroupContainerIdentifier:)`
> method.

This means that you cannot read Safari cookies from `HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for:)` because it only applies to your sandboxed app and they will not be stored there.

Only `SFSafariViewController` would be capable of using Safari cookies, but you have no programmatic access there anyway.